# imagen ticket visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Me gustaría pedir ayuda para poner una imagen como encabezado de un ticket. He estado buscando y no sé como es el código, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar

Esta es la parte donde mando a imprimir, no se si es en esta parte o es en otra donde habría que agregar algo, también pido perdón si es un problema fácil estoy empezando con esto de la programación pero no he encontrado una solución para este problema

```
    public void ImprimirTicket(string impresora)
    {
        //Este metodo recibe el nombre de la impresora a la cual se mandara a imprimir y el texto que se imprimira.
        //Usaremos un código que nos proporciona Microsoft. https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/322091
        //impresora = "POS-80C";
        //string img = "";
        //RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter(impresora,"imagen.jpeg");
        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(impresora, linea.ToString());
        linea.Clear();//Al cabar de imprimir limpia la linea de todo el texto agregado.
    }

}

//Clase para mandara a imprimir texto plano a la impresora
public class RawPrinterHelper
{
 
public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length;
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }
}
//
```